# Error from adehabitatLT::as.ltraj() because dates are not class POSIXct but str(dates) indicates they are POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct, adehabitathr

The [adehabitatLR::as.ltraj()](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/adehabitatLT/html/as.ltraj.html) function calculates animal trajectories. The function requires dates to be class POSIXct. I followed the same steps in the example section of the help document using a play dataset I found online and converted date-time to POSIXct dates but I still get the following error when running the function

> Error in adehabitatLT::as.ltraj(xy = xy[id == "17", ], date = date[id
> ==  :    For objects of type II,  date should be of class "POSIXct"

Here is what I'm doing...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rio)
library(sp)
library(adehabitatLT)

#import elk collar data
data<-import("https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/59d90ceee4b05fe04cc9b0f2?f=__disk__a8%2F84%2Fa6%2Fa884a68596e8ed85b6b956119db0f1fffc4e960c")
glimpse(data)
#following example: convert date-time to posixct, and ID to character
elk<-data%>%mutate(date=as.POSIXct(strptime(Date_Time_MST,"%m/%d/%Y",tz="US/Mountain")))%>%mutate(AID=as.character(AID))
#get id vector
id<-elk%>%dplyr::select(AID)
#get xy data
xy<-elk%>%dplyr::select(Easting, Northing)%>%coordinates()%>%as.data.frame()
#get dates
date<-elk%>%dplyr::select(date)%>%as.data.frame()
str(date)
#get trajectories for AID 17
tr<-adehabitatLT::as.ltraj(xy=xy[id=="17",],date=date[id=="17"], id="17")
```

Comment: Your `date` is a dataframe, don't mistake a frame with one column of `POSIXct` with a vector of class `POSIXct`, they are not equivalent. I don't know why you're breaking things out of your frame, I'd likely do something like `tr <- with(elk[elk$id=="17",], as.ltraj(xy=xy, date=date, id="17"))` (or similar ... I don't have that package either but the premise should work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `date` object is *not* of class `POSIXct`, it is a `data.frame`. Don't mistake a frame with one column (that happens to be `POSIXct`) equivalent for functions as a `POSIXct` vector.

Also, I see no reason to break it out into individual vectors, that leaves room for inconsistent indexing, etc. I suggest something like this:

```r
elk <- data %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(Date_Time_MST, format = "%m/%d/%Y", tz  ="US/Mountain"))) %>%
  mutate(AID = as.character(AID))

tr <- with(elk[elk$AID == "17",],
           as.ltraj(xy = coordinates(cbind(Easting, Northing), date = date, id = AID))
```

If you're going to be doing this one-call for multiple `id`s (or even all of them) in `elk` and want to automate it, you can generate a list-column (saved for later use) with something like:

```r
elk_with_tr <- elk %>%
  filter(id %in% c("17", ...)) %>%        # some other IDs of interest to you
  mutate(
    tr = Map(as.ltraj, xy=coordinates(cbind(Easting, Northing)), date=date, id=AID)
  )
```

and this new frame will have a `list`-column named `tr` with all of the results.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I ended up running into other errors though (e.g., xy does not exist in elk) but ultimately I think I sorted it out...elk1<-elk%>%
  dplyr::select(AID,Easting, Northing, date)%>%
  distinct()%>%
  nest(data=-AID)%>%
  mutate(traj=map2(AID,data,~as.ltraj(xy=data.frame(x=.y$Easting, y=.y$Northing),date=.y$date,id=.x)))

Comment: Oops, right, your `xy` was two columns, I hastened over that and did it wrong ... editing for clarity, sorry about that ...